# How to use smart reply custom ops in python or tfjs?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to implement smart reply tflite model in python or tfjs, but they are using custom ops. Please refer https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/smart_reply/android/app/libs/cc.

So how to build that custom op separately and use that custom op in python or tfjs?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do with the custom ops. The custom ops used by that example model are not really useful, unless you are training a different model. If you want to just do "smart reply" that example is probably what you want to use. However, this model is not really aimed at production use. It is more a demo of what you could build with more data and work.

Comment: @aselle Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to implement "smart reply" in tfjs or python. But i cannot able to use the smartreply.tflite directly due to custom ops. So is there any option to use the smart reply custom ops directly in tfjs or python?